# Executing only part of the code in Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, c-preprocessor, visual-studio-debugging

I have some `C++` code that I'd like to debug. As it's often the case, my bug appears only in certain conditions that cannot be reproduced with tiny datasets, and it appears after going through multiple functions that I am sure work.

In particular, I first need to put all my data in an `std::set` which is very slow in `debug mode` (and reasonable in release), even when using an `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0` preprocessor directive. As such, I was thinking that there might have been a way to execute part of the code in release while only executing the relevant buggy part of the code in debug mode.

I tried doing something like :

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#define MODIFIED_DEBUG
#define NDEBUG
#endif

// build my expensive datastructure etc. etc.

#ifdef MODIFIED_DEBUG
#undef MODIFIED_DEBUG
#undef NDEBUG
#define _DEBUG
#endif

// execute my buggy code
```

However, this is still as slow as in `debug mode`. I there any (easy) way to get the speed of the `release mode` only for part of my code ? Especially, since the slowness is mostly due to the `STL`.

(I guess I could compile a `.lib` that builds the data structure in release and use the library in my code in debug mode, but that's quite a pain just to debug a program!).
Alternatively, is there any trick like the `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0` definition to speed up the `STL` in debug mode ? I am using `Visual Studio 2010`.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio very much, but in GCC, a lot of debugging functionality is signaled by build flags rather than defines, though VC++ may be different. Since you're using the STL, all the code is written in the headers for your template. Make sure anything you don't want defined is `#undef`'d BEFORE `#include`ing your STL header. This will affect all uses of that STL class throughout your code though.

Comment: since STD datastructures are templated, doesn't that mean the code is only compiled when used ? So that, only when I declare my `std::set<MyClass>` variable is the STL code compiled (and the `#define` used) ?

Comment: That's not necessarily the case. I haven't waded through the internals of any C++ compiler, but I'm very familiar with the CPP. When you `#include` the template header, it literally just dumps the header file in to your code where the `#include` is. Any `#define`s that you have will be in full effect where you `#include` the header, not where you use the templates in your code.

Comment: I think it does not behave the same with Visual Studio and GCC. For instance, with Visual Studio, you can literally have a header file with `template<typename T> class Toto { Toto(){undefined garbage;} };` and if you include the header file, your code will still compile as long as you don't use this class. I think with GCC this is not the case for instance.

Comment: Well, I have a student ISO of Visual Studio 2012 on my computer. I'll install it and run some tests. I'll get back to you in an hour or so.

Answer (score 2):

You can build in release mode and surround the suspect code with

```
#pragma optimize("",off)
//...
#pragma optimize("",on)
```

or do it old-school - debug statements.

Comment: thanks, but does building in release still allow me to get the same functionnalities as in debug ? (like getting the correct addresses of the variables, their actual values etc.). What do you mean by "debug statements" ?

Comment: @WhitAngl well, that depends. Surround code you want to inspect with the pragmas. For others, the debugger might not be of that much help. Debug statements mean `std::cout << x;` :)

Comment: mmm, apparently this doesn't allow me to inspect the value of the variables which is the main point of debug mode ;) This also requires the code to be debugged to be in its own function (for the pragma to work). And printing variable values is less than practical in a loop that iterates millions of times with different values each and a crash for particular unknown values.... I'll wait a little bit more for other answers before validating. Thanks!